# Is it possible to stop running a PHP script and rerun it automatically locally?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP script that could take **more than 30 minutes** running , I'm running PHP locally using "**Xampp**" , I'm wondering if there is a way to stop the script if a condition is true and rerun it where it stopped automatically? , I mean for example if I'm dealing with **about 1500 files** on my computer and I'm extracting data from them , Is it possible to stop the running process after a specific number of files and then restart from this file ? , I could change **max_execution_time()** function to change the maximum time the script should take , but I'm afraid of running out of memory (I have **2GB Ram**) or any error happens running the script for all this time , Is there is a way to achieve that ? like starting the script again to avoid running the script for this long?

Comment: Run your files in batches. Say 100, or 10 or 1000, trial and error.

Comment: What has this todo with js, nodejs and python????!?!

Comment: @Andrew , Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: @Jim For instance, only input 100 files rather than the full 1500.

Comment: @JonasW. , Maybe there is something related to them that could achieve what I want , like ajax could be used and it's nor related to PHP

Comment: Well, the concept itself is pretty self explanatory. Instead of doing all 1500 files at once, do 10 at a time. Remember the last file you extracted data from and start from there + 1 on the next run.

Comment: @ProEvilz , It's for saving time not to be done manually

Comment: Why this question was closed with link to another question, not very related to this one?

Comment: @Andrew , That's what I want to do , but how to stop and restart it to deal with the next 10 files?

Comment: @RauliRajande , I don't know this is very strange!

Comment: I wrote an answer, but can't answer. Basically, there are 2 options 1) ajax and 2) simple queue manager with crontab check. When running php from command line, you don't have the time limit.

Comment: It would be better to run your script in CLI mode **or** with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to 0.

Comment: Can't this question be opened and this "duplicate" removed?

Comment: @Andrew , What is CLI mode ? , set_time_limit to 0 , As I said this may cause an error or a problem with the computer memory

Comment: CLI mode is terminal mode(when you're not running it in a browser basically). You can clean up the memory by [forcing garbage collection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) (if any) and/or unsetting whatever variables you don't need.